# Class 'Auth' not found in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, api

Here Is my routes in `api.php`. After Authentication i am not getting the user details in other route

```
Route::post('/login','CustomLogin@userLogin');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::post('/change-password','ChangePassword@changePassword');
});

public function changePassword(ChangepassRequest $request){
         $user = Auth::user();
         print_r($user);
         die();
    }
```

Update: I was new in laravel then.. So the Actual Problem was class `Auth` not found! Thank You For the Comments! 
I am updating my answer as well !

Comment: please add which route and which function

Comment: Route::post('/change-password','ChangePassword@changePassword');

Comment: it is protected by api middleware so  you have to setup token system then you will get auth user

Comment: Where **exactly** does this code return anything like `null`?

Comment: Solved: I was not sending the token which i generated when i created the login api thats why !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution Was adding The `use Auth` in my Controller! That's All

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something wrong with your login method if you have set up all correctly in the token system.

you can use the below snippet to log in users, which might change as per your credentials.

```
<?php 

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if (request::has(['email', 'password'])) {

            $user = User::whereEmailAndPassword(request()->get('email'),request()->get('password'))->first();
            $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

            if ($user and $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['message' => 'Login Successful', 'jwt_token'=>$token], 200);
            } else {
                return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
            }

        } else {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Pease provide your email and password to login'], 401);
        }
    }
}
```

And Of course, there is a thousand of way to do this same thing

Answer (score 0):

You comment $user line so this variable not declare at all.

> ```
>     // $user = Auth::user();
> ```

You should uncomment it :))